# Concatenate Specific Code on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe, concatenation

I am new with CodeIgniter, how to display this url below using concatenate on codeigniter:

```
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="http://domain.com.ABC123.html" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

- URL : http://domain.com.ABC123.html
- KEY :  ABC123 (Stored in database and there will be different code for each users)

I need to concatenate the KEY only for each active users.

Comment: And ... what have you tried so far? Can we see your code?

Comment: The same way you would do it in any PHP script

Comment: is `.com.ABC123.html` even valid? i think not

Comment: sorry @Alex my mistake to type it. thank you

Comment: Still keep searching and testing right now. thanks @kerbholz

Comment: yes, will do! Thank you @RiggsFolly